# Findfirst matching long integers incorrectly

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao, data-access-object

**Objective**: Set a recordset using a query string, then perform `FindFirst = number` to find a specific ID, and therefore record, in the recordset.

**Problem**: The recordset is generated correctly but `FindFirst` consistently, incorrectly matches IDs below a certain value.

**Description**: When I create a recordset inner (or left or right) joining Task and Task_Entry matching specific CycleID and TaskDataID values I get a list of records (in my recordset, I ensure TaskID isn't ambiguous). If I `FindFirst` any value below 1469, `FindFirst` returns the 1469 record, every time. See example records and structure below.

**Original Query** (put into a `CurrentDB.OpenRecordset()`): 
`"SELECT Datetime, TaskDataID, SigID, Task_Entry.*  FROM Task INNER JOIN Task_Entry ON Task_Entry.TaskID = Task.TaskID  WHERE Task.CycleID = " & inputCycleID & " AND Task.TaskDataID = " & inputTaskDataID & " ORDER BY Task.TaskID"`

**Table Structure**:

- Two tables bound via autonumber ID field:
- Task contains general task information (date time, signature ID, etc)
- Task_Entry contains a subset of Entry specific information
- Not all records in Task are related to Task_Entry

**Example records**:
**Task**: *TaskID, Datetime, TaskDataID, CycleID, SigId*
1447 03/09/16 15 ***7*** 1495 *(the TaskDataID was different)*
... other records
1469 03/15/16 15 8 1518
... other records

**Task_Entry**: *TaskID, Data1, Data2* 
1447 929 930.5 
1469 919 922

**Troubleshooting**:

- Originally performed `FindFirst` in VBA using: `rst.FindFirst "TaskID = " & inputTaskID` where inputTaskID was a variant.

  - The datatype did not matter. Forced datatype to Long and still matched 1447 to 1469 somehow.
- Changed recordset to only return TaskID = inputTaskID.

  - `"SELECT Datetime, TaskDataID, SigID, Task_Entry.*  FROM Task INNER JOIN Task_Entry ON Task_Entry.TaskID = Task.TaskID WHERE Task.TaskID = " & inputTaskID`
  - This worked; returns one record matching inputTaskID.
  - I have use cases for returning the entire set the matches CycleID and TaskDataID, so I would still like to know why this doesn't work.

Comment: Do you see the same behavior with a simpler "select distinct TaskId from Task" query?

Comment: Yes. Just ran the above 'original query' adding DISTINCT and removing the ORDER BY (because it threw an error about a conflict). Same mismatch 1469 = 1447.

Comment: What's the value of `rst.NoMatch` when that happens ? Does the value of the Field change from before performing the Findfirst?

Comment: Aaaa! True?!?! Why is it true?! And why would it return a wrong number. Ugh!

Comment: It's true because there is no match (so the current record has not changed).  As for why there's no match - if you print out all of the values is the one you're looking for in the output?

Comment: @TimWilliams You're right. It's not in there; constraining the data too much with the original query. That's why the second query works; I'm removing the TaskDataID constraint which changed for earlier entries (my fake data posted above is wrong). So it returns (or just remains on) the first record of reoordset?

Comment: Are you specifying what type of recordset you want when you execute the query?  I think FindFirst only works with certain types (Dynaset, Snapshot)

Comment: @AndrewMorton you're right. I was sloppy modifying the code to post here. It is correct in the database. I will update above.

Comment: Problem solved. @TimWilliams care to post an answer or should I summarize?

Comment: Feel free to post an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `FindFirst` is used on a recordset and results in `NoMatch` being true, the recordset remains on the current record.

In this specific case, the original query over-constrained the records on the TaskDataID parameter returning a set of records not containing the ID being searched for. Performing `FindFirst` left the recordset on the first record (which in this case was the one with TaskID = 1469).